Varying sequence lengths between classes in LSTM
I am working on a project where the goal is to predict whether students in an online course will drop out of the course. The course is divided into 20 course weeks. For each week, I have certain kinds of data that indicate performance or behavior.
Users that have fully finished the course have data for each of the 20 course weeks. These are the non-dropout users. Users that dropped out of the course have data for a fewer amount of weeks, depending on how far into the course they made it before they dropped out.
I now want to try to train an LSTM model to capture behavior and engagement patterns across weeks, and be able to predict the dropout label (0 for non-dropout, 1 for dropout). My question is:
Does it matter that dropout users have shorter sequence lengths than non-dropout users? Will the model associate a shorter sequence length with dropout?
This would be problematic, as I want to eventually deploy the model on a dataset of students currently taking the course in order to predict whether they might drop out. But of course, these students would also have a sequence length shorter than 20.
I thought about using a truncated version of the data for the non-dropout users, i.e. use a user's data up to a certain course week, to mimic the incomplete data of dropout users. Then the model has examples of both dropout users and non-dropout users for each sequence length. But is this necessary? Or can I use the full sequence length of non-dropout users without the model associating a shorter sequence length with dropout?


Will the model associate a shorter sequence length with dropout?

Well, I would certainly hope so! If you have students with $20$ data points, all of which completed the course, and others with less than $20$ data points, all of which drop out, then the length of the input data is a perfect predictor for whether a student drops out!
Plus, you don't even need to train a silicon NN to model this, your biological one is absolutely up to this job: "This student has fewer than $20$ data points? They dropped out!"
And of course, as you write subsequently, this is not the problem you want to address:

This would be problematic, as I want to eventually deploy the model on a dataset of students currently taking the course in order to predict whether they might drop out. But of course, these students would also have a sequence length shorter than 20.

By the point in time where you want to predict whether a given student will drop out, you will be $N<20$ weeks into the course. (Because after $20$ weeks, per above, you don't need a model any more to know who dropped out.) And you will only know how many data points you have out of $N$, rather than out of $20$ - because the remaining $20-N$ data points are yet to come in, or not.
So the important predictor is not how many data points someone has throughout the course, but how many data points someone has up to this point.

I thought about using a truncated version of the data for the non-dropout users, i.e. use a user's data up to a certain course week, to mimic the incomplete data of dropout users. Then the model has examples of both dropout users and non-dropout users for each sequence length. But is this necessary? Or can I use the full sequence length of non-dropout users without the model associating a shorter sequence length with dropout?

I would say that this is indeed necessary to the extent you want your model to be of any use in production. Nothing keeps you from using training data you have available as a form of practice. However, the model you train here will be predicated on you knowing all the data points, on you knowing how people perform throughout the course even if you are only halfway through. I don't see how this is of any use. In "production", you would only feed in the first $N$ (or fewer) data points in week $N$, and your model will interpret this as not having any more data, and will cheerfully "predict" that everyone dropped out after week $N$ - because, after all, for all the model knows, nobody had any more weekly data after that point.
So I would indeed work with truncated data. Figure out when you will want to ask your model who will be likely to drop out, and use only training data up to this point, along with the known target of subsequent dropping out. Yes, that may mean that you want to train multiple models, one to predict after 5 weeks, one to predict after 10 weeks, one to predict after 15 weeks. You might be able to build a sophisticated omnibus model that models everything together, but that would be quite a bit more complicated.
(Also, keep in mind that people may have fewer than 20 data points and still not drop out, because they were sick or similar.)

Thank you for the detailed reply, this is very useful. Do you think I should truncate both data of dropouts and non-dropouts? For example, if a user drops out in week 12, should I include their data truncated to week 5 for the model trained on data up to week 5? Because I suppose it is possible that the patterns that indicate the user might drop out are not present at that stage yet. For non-dropouts, it is different, because we know they continued after this point, so we can assume they were engaged in the course.

I would use training data as indicated by how I plan on using the model in production. If I want to use the model in week 5, then I would only use data up to week 5, for both dropouts and non. If patterns are not visible by this time, then they won't be visible on the production data, either, and this will simply increase the residual uncertainty - but simulating knowledge about this by using "future" training data will mislead our model.
